# AjaxBehavior added at runtime but AjaxBehaviorListener is not invoked

Tags: java, ajax, jsf

I am trying to add some ajax behaviour in a `<h:inputText>` component at runtime.
I spent a day to figure out what is going wrong with the next code with no success.

After invoking the `initUIComponent` method, the component indeed triggers ajax requests, a normal ajax response is also returned. However the AjaxBehaviorListener is never invoked. What have I missed? I use glassfish 3.1.2.2 with the default mojarra implementation.

```
public void initUIComponent(HtmlInputText c) {
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    AjaxBehavior ajaxBeh = (AjaxBehavior) fc.getApplication() .createBehavior(AjaxBehavior.BEHAVIOR_ID);
    ajaxBeh.setRender(Collections.singletonList("elId1"));
    ajaxBeh.setExecute(Collections.singletonList("@this"));
    ajaxBeh.addAjaxBehaviorListener(new AjaxBehaviorListener() {
        @Override
        public void processAjaxBehavior(AjaxBehaviorEvent e)
                throws AbortProcessingException {
            System.out.println("Something is happening!");

        }
    });
    c.addClientBehavior("keyup", ajaxBeh);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it seems that this is a Mojarra bug. The code works smoothly with MyFaces. [Here](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2674) is the related Jira issue (JAVASERVERFACES-2674).